# Package errors on install Crx/de - no logs - AEM 6.3

Tags: aem, crx

When attempting to upload and install a file created via `./mvnw clean install` I'm running into the error below:

```
Install Package: /etc/packages/apple-cms/cms-content-v1.zip

Mon Mar 19 2018 15:53:13 GMT-0400 (EDT)

Installing content    
Collecting import information...    
Installing node types...
Installing privileges...
Importing content...
- /
... (contents of installation truncated)
saving approx 1 nodes...
Package imported (with errors, check logs!)
```

Content is missing from the crx/de tree under /etc/map/publish/http - so I wish to check the logs.

Attempting to tail all of the logs under ../author/crx-quickstart/logs but not getting any output at all - same for both publish and authoring instance.

`filter.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
  <filter root="/apps/apple-members"/>
  <filter root="/apps/sling" mode="update"/>
  <filter root="/etc/clientlibs/apple-members"/>
  <filter root="/etc/map.publish" mode="update"/>
  <filter root="/etc/designs/apple-members/fonts" mode="update"/>
  <filter root="/etc/designs/apple-members/images" mode="update"/>
  <filter root="/etc/designs/apple-members/styles" mode="update"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```

Comment: Can you please attach the relevant parts of your `error.log`?

Comment: Just go to the package manager (/crx/packmgr), and re-install the package manually. Then you can see the log. An alternative could be Parameter at the maven plugin. But I cannot look it up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no real log-entries created by the package manager.

You have 3 options to see the package manager output.

1. Go to the pacakge manager http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/index.jsp and re-install the package manually.
2. Set the content-package-maven-plugin in verbose mode on the command line with:

   `mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage -Dvault.verbose=true`
3. Enable the verbose mode in the pom.xml file permanently.

   `<groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <extensions>true</extensions>
         <configuration>
              <verbose>true</verbose>
              ...`

Comment: I only used Maven to build the package. I manually installed it to the URL you posted (/crx/packmgr) which informed me to check the logs.

Comment: 1. Could you post your filter.xml file? (inside the content-package.zip under  META-INF\vault), 2. As which user are you logged in, while installing the package? 3. There should be something in the error.log - even if it seems totally unrelated to your package. Can you check what gets written into the error.log, when clicking install?

Comment: 4. Can you also unzip the content package and check, if it looks good? So inside the jcr_root folder is the content structure you expect. There are also .content.xml files in each folder?

Comment: Looks like a couple of `.content.xml` files were missing. I added those and now I am seeing an error in one of my `dialog.xml` files that has two root elements (not sure how that ever worked...)

Answer (score 5):

You can see what happens during installation of a package in packagemanager by creating a custom log on

*org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.impl*

at DEBUG or TRACE level.

You can find how to create a custom log [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/deploying/using/configure-logging.html#CreatingYourOwnLoggersandWriters), basically e.g. directly in the OSGi-Felix-Console in [Log Support](http://localhost:4502/system/console/slinglog).

- Log Level    Debug
- Log File logs/packagemanager.log
- Message Pattern  {0,date,dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} *{4}* [{2}] {3} {5}
- Logger   org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.impl

The log entries will show up in the folder cq-quickstart/logs/packagemanager.log.