# Adobe AEM package manager - how to show Activity log using curl

Tags: curl, aem

I am using curl to automate AEM package manager, but I would like to see the actual progress. What I am seeing in /crx/packmgr/index.jsp in the window on the lower right.

So for example if I build or install a large package, curls progress only shows me that it's still busy/waiting, but not what is actually going on.

I would like to see the log output like

```
Building package
A META-INF
A META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
A META-INF/vault
A META-INF/vault/config.xml
A META-INF/vault/filter.xml
A META-INF/vault/nodetypes.cnd
A META-INF/vault/properties.xml
A /.content.xml
A /content
A /content/.content.xml
...
Package built in 407377ms.
```

If there a way to get this info for the POST request

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST 
'http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service/.json/etc/packages/my_packages
 /allmycontent-1.0.zip?cmd=build'
```

or can I get some other url to see the activity log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy way to do this using the following way:

```
curl -ku admin:admin -F file=@"package-1.0.zip" -F force=true http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp

curl -F cmd=install -F extractOnly=true "http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service/script.html/etc/packages/my_packages/package-1.0.zip"
```

The second command will print the progress as HTML output, e.g. the same that gets shown in the activity window in the package manager.

Answer (score -1):

please have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50325299/1514647

when adding a logger for the `org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.impl.ActivityLog` it will create entries:

```
05.05.2022 09:00:00.024 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.impl.ActivityLog group:packagname:1.0.0: CREATE
05.05.2022 09:00:00.024 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.impl.ActivityLog group:packagname:1.0.0: UPLOAD
05.05.2022 09:00:00.105 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.impl.ActivityLog group:packagname:1.0.0: EXTRACT_SUB_PACKAGES ()
```

Local access of logs:
After that you can do a `tail -f error.log` in the `crx-quickstart/logs` folder

Remote access of logs:
http://host:port/system/console/slinglog/tailer.txt?tail=10000&grep=*&name=%2Flogs%2Ferror.log

Comment: Thanks, but the logs are only available locally on the same machine - I am looking for a way to access this from remote (e.g. my Jenkins instance), e.g. some URL as I said in my question.

Comment: The maven verbose option in the linked post switches on logging, but it does not say how to access the log data.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. I think it's possible via the url `http://host:port/system/console/slinglog/tailer.txt?tail=10000&grep=*&name=%2Flogs%2Ferror.log`

Before you need to turn on the loggers as described above. You can also write to a different log file, to have the package installation log separated. You need to submit Basic Auth.